# Where did Caliban come from?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

In the movie **Logan** we can see Caliban along with Charles and Logan. But Caliban was last seen in X-Men Apocalypse. How was he particularly chosen to be in Logan? And why wasn't he affected because of Charles uncontrollable mind because every other mutant was dead by his doing.

Answer (score 2):

It has been a while since I watched Logan, but (as I recall) Charles Xavier's "mindquakes":

1. Affect Mutants and Non-Mutants equally - and humanity is not extinct
2. Have a limited sphere of influence (although, theoretically, this would effectively vanish with Cerebro)

It is then not a case that *"every other mutant was dead by his doing"* - rather, the mutants (and non-mutants) who were **in his vicinity** at the time were affected and, in the incident you are referencing, died.  This presumably includes the X-Men, and students at the School.

(Assuming that either he was still the headmaster, or the school was still based out of his ancestral home)

Comment: This is a very valid point, the Westminster incident eliminated only the X-men. But currently, this doesn't answer OP's questions about Caliban.